# Merge (video and audio) with (background music) with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have video file input.mp4 that contain video and two audio source - speaking, and music.mp3 that contain background music. Now, I want to merge them.

Here is the command that i use:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i music.mp3 -c:v copy -filter_complex "[0:a]aformat = fltp:44100:stereo,apad[0a];[1] aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,volume=1.5[1a];[0a] [1a] amerge[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -ac 2 -y -shortest output.mp4
```

input file
https://d9f35555a8b3e9044c8d-95c21efaab8093d23d4124e599a618ee.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/mub_audio/1e03dc67-5079-46d5-b692-d69bbb6ee3e3.mp4

audio file
https://d9f35555a8b3e9044c8d-95c21efaab8093d23d4124e599a618ee.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/mub_audio/a6cab88a63eb11eb8d8b901b0efa6f1d.mp3

you can check the output file here
https://d9f35555a8b3e9044c8d-95c21efaab8093d23d4124e599a618ee.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/mub_audio/6e6e79ef-a732-49d9-8317-4ba97c05a352.mp4

The input file has a pause after every sentence. But in output, that pause duration doesn't have any background music.
What can be the reason? what is the solution for it?

Comment: Most likely, there are no actual audio packets during the silence. Insert `aresample=async=1` to the input audio after aformat.

Comment: Thanks Gyan, This solution worked.